# R: plotting 2 polygon shapefiles, problems with CRS & extent

Tags: coordinate-system, r, plot

I am trying to create a map using 2 shapefiles, both of which have been subset. I am plotting municipalities of a census district in Canada.

For the census district, I am using the [census division boundary file from StatCan] (http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2016-eng.cfm). For the municipalities, I am using [CanVec files from Natural Resources Canada] (http://geogratis.gc.ca/api/en/nrcan-rncan/ess-sst/23387971-b6d3-4ded-a40b-c8e832b4ea08.html#distribution).

I have subset both files to cover the census district of interest and want to plot the CanVec administrative features (towns) on top of the district.  Individually, both plot okay, but

```
plot(towns,
     add = TRUE)
```

does not add the towns.  Nothing happens, no error.

I checked the CRS and found that my 'cd' (Census Division) uses NAD83. Documentation for the CanVec file, subset to 'towns', says it also uses NAD83, but my output looks like this:

```
proj4string(towns)
"+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs"
```

So, I ran:

```
proj4string(towns) <- CRS("+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +lat_0=63.390675 
           +lon_0=-91.86666666666666 +x_0=6200000 +y_0=3000000 
           +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 
           +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

Now, CRS looks normal, but they still did not both plot, so I checked extent and found they don't overlap at all.

```
extent(cd)
extent(towns)

> extent(cd)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 5986825 
xmax        : 6267206 
ymin        : 1322528 
ymax        : 1474248 
> extent(towns)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -94.81746 
xmax        : -91.4896 
ymin        : 48.51538 
ymax        : 49.36678
```

My search of SE got me this far, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Just from the numbers it looks like the second extent is still in degrees.

Comment: Yes, that occurred to me too, but I wasn't sure what to do about it. Some more research later, I understand that #2 needs to be transformed into a projected coordinate system.

Comment: I did spTransform (apparently incorrectly) and it did not change the units. I've been reviewing the documentation at http://proj4.org but am still struggling.

Answer (score 2):

Problem has been fixed.  It was indeed an issue of using two different coordinate systems, and my misunderstanding of how to correctly use spTransform.

I ran the following and was able to complete the plot:

```
towns <- spTransform(towns, CRS("+init=epsg:4269"))
```

Comment: Yeah, basically the plot is not metadata-aware like a good GIS map would be. Some of ggplot2 is, and there are partial auto-projection bits and pieces around - but a good example is mapview package which will always put layers into a common coordinate system, though Mercator is the easiest and the default - it's good for early exploration at least.

Comment: `Mapview`is useful for visualizing spatial data easily and interacting with it (like a GIS program) but it is not intended for producing presentation quality map and, as such, is not a replacement for other GIS packages in R.

Comment: `tmap` package can handle different CRS but still produce presentation quality maps